# KCFinder for Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, kcfinder

I installed KCFinder extension in my yii2 application via composer.
In view I using next code:

```
        use iutbay\yii2kcfinder\KCFinderInputWidget;

        echo KCFinderInputWidget::widget([
            'name' => 'file',
        ]);
```

Widget works but I can't upload files because there is no 'Upload' button in widget.

Comment: I guess by default there is no ability for uploading. Did you rewrite options and set them in session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check widget description,  https://github.com/iutbay/yii2-kcfinder. You need set option 'access.files.upload' in 'true'.

```
   $kcfOptions = array_merge(KCFinder::$kcfDefaultOptions, [
        'uploadURL' => Yii::getAlias('@web').'/upload',
        'access' => [
            'files' => [
                'upload' => true,
                .......
        ],
    ]);

    // Set kcfinder session options
    Yii::$app->session->set('KCFINDER', $kcfOptions);
```

You should rewrite options after  you created widget